# Fetching graph from Neo4j to Spark

Tags: apache-spark, neo4j, cypher

I a working on integrating `Spark` with `Neo4j`. 
`Spark` Version: `2.1.0`
`Neo4j` Version: `3.1.6` community edition
I am using `neo4j-spark-connector-2.0.0-M2.jar` to connect.

**Problem:**
Unable to load the Graph as I am getting following error:

```
ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 21)
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalNode cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToLong(BoxesRunTime.java:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Row$class.getLong(Row.scala:231)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow.getLong(rows.scala:165)
    at org.neo4j.spark.Neo4j$$anonfun$2.apply(Neo4j.scala:218)
    at org.neo4j.spark.Neo4j$$anonfun$2.apply(Neo4j.scala:218)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.graphx.EdgeRDD$$anonfun$1.apply(EdgeRDD.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.graphx.EdgeRDD$$anonfun$1.apply(EdgeRDD.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1$$anonfun$apply$26.apply(RDD.scala:843)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1$$anonfun$apply$26.apply(RDD.scala:843)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$8.apply(RDD.scala:336)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$8.apply(RDD.scala:334)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:957)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:948)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:888)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:948)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:694)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:334)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/09/04 14:01:10 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 3.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 24)
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalNode cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToLong(BoxesRunTime.java:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Row$class.getLong(Row.scala:231)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow.getLong(rows.scala:165)
    at org.neo4j.spark.Neo4j$$anonfun$2.apply(Neo4j.scala:218)
    at org.neo4j.spark.Neo4j$$anonfun$2.apply(Neo4j.scala:218)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.graphx.EdgeRDD$$anonfun$1.apply(EdgeRDD.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.graphx.EdgeRDD$$anonfun$1.apply(EdgeRDD.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1$$anonfun$apply$26.apply(RDD.scala:843)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1$$anonfun$apply$26.apply(RDD.scala:843)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$8.apply(RDD.scala:336)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$8.apply(RDD.scala:334)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:957)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:948)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:888)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:948)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:694)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:334)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/09/04 14:01:10 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 2.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 23)
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalNode cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToLong(BoxesRunTime.java:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Row$class.getLong(Row.scala:231)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow.getLong(rows.scala:165)
    at org.neo4j.spark.Neo4j$$anonfun$2.apply(Neo4j.scala:218)
    at org.neo4j.spark.Neo4j$$anonfun$2.apply(Neo4j.scala:218)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.graphx.EdgeRDD$$anonfun$1.apply(EdgeRDD.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.graphx.EdgeRDD$$anonfun$1.apply(EdgeRDD.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1$$anonfun$apply$26.apply(RDD.scala:843)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1$$anonfun$apply$26.apply(RDD.scala:843)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$8.apply(RDD.scala:336)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$8.apply(RDD.scala:334)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:957)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:948)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:888)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:948)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:694)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:334)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/09/04 14:01:10 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 22)
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalNode cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToLong(BoxesRunTime.java:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Row$class.getLong(Row.scala:231)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow.getLong(rows.scala:165)
    at org.neo4j.spark.Neo4j$$anonfun$2.apply(Neo4j.scala:218)
    at org.neo4j.spark.Neo4j$$anonfun$2.apply(Neo4j.scala:218)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.graphx.EdgeRDD$$anonfun$1.apply(EdgeRDD.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.graphx.EdgeRDD$$anonfun$1.apply(EdgeRDD.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1$$anonfun$apply$26.apply(RDD.scala:843)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1$$anonfun$apply$26.apply(RDD.scala:843)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$8.apply(RDD.scala:336)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$8.apply(RDD.scala:334)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:957)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:948)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:888)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:948)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:694)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:334)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Following is the query sample which I using:

> MATCH (n)-[b]-(a) where b.NodeType = "Technology" return n,b,a

Spark Code snippet

```
import org.neo4j.spark._
import org.apache.spark.graphx._
import org.apache.spark.graphx.lib._

val neo = Neo4j(sc)

// load graph via Cypher query
val graphQuery = """MATCH (n)-[b]-(a) where b.NodeType = "Technology" return n,b,a"""
val graph: Graph[Long, String] = neo.rels(graphQuery).partitions(7).batch(200).loadGraph

graph.vertices.count <--- ERROR
```

Also I have noticed that If we fetch the graph which has only one type of relations then it works but Multiple relation types does'nt.

Is there any work-around for this ? Please suggest.

Comment: Could you raise an issue on the repository for the spark-connector?

Comment: @MichaelHunger Hi, I have created the issue in neo4j-spark-connector repo https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-spark-connector/issues/45